# VOIP Call recording for PJSIP Library not working

Tags: ios, voip, pjsip

Unable to record PJSIP Call in ios code. I am using PJSIP 2.2 version.
Following is my code

```
pjsua_recorder_id recorder_id;
pj_status_t status;
NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *strPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/mysong.wav", documentsDirectory];
pj_str_t fileName = pj_str([strPath UTF8String]);
status = pjsua_recorder_create(&fileName, 0, NULL, 0, 0, &recorder_id);
NSLog(@"status is = %i", status);


int way = 1 << 0;
static int BITMASK_IN = 1 << 0;
static int BITMASK_OUT = 1 << 1;

if(status == PJ_SUCCESS)
{
        pjsua_recorder_id recorder_id;
            pj_status_t status;
        int wavPort = pjsua_recorder_get_conf_port(0);
        if ((way & BITMASK_IN) == BITMASK_IN) {
            int wavConfPort = -1;//callInfo.getConfPort();
            pjsua_conf_connect(0, wavPort);
        }
        if ((way & BITMASK_OUT) == BITMASK_OUT) {
            pjsua_conf_connect(0, wavPort);
        }
        wavPort = pjsua_call_get_conf_port(0);
        pjsua_conf_connect(0, wavPort);


        status = pjsua_recorder_create(&fileName, 0, NULL, 0, 0, &recorder_id);
    NSLog(@"final status is = %i", status);

}
```

Value of Status is 0(PJ_SUCCESS), but still unable to play .wav file. To play .wav file,

```
// get files list
NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
NSLog(@"Array of files = %@", directoryContents);

//Play audio file
NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/mysong.wav",documentsDirectory];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:soundFileURL options:nil];


AVAudioPlayer *theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:NULL];
theAudio.volume = 1.0;
theAudio.delegate = self;
[theAudio prepareToPlay];
[theAudio play];
```

In array of file I am able to get recorded .wav file.

Comment: did you solved this problem?

Comment: I don't know why but the status returned to me is 120002. 

status = pjsua_recorder_create(&fileName, 0, NULL, 0, 0, &recorder_id);